# Debugging grammar with Antlworks

Tags: antlrworks

I recently discovered AntlrWorks and I'm trying to debug my grammar (edited with Xtext, Eclipse and MWE).

I configured javac path and classpath, but antlrworks is still complaining :

"cannot find symbol: class DebugAbstractInternalAntlrParser"

Does anybody have already faced this issue?

Thanks